# Google Apps Script - Auto Tasks Assignment / Allocation

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

Spreadsheet's first tab name = '**Source**'

Column headers in Source = *Task-ID, Task-Details, Assigned-To*

Spreadsheet's second tab name = '**Assignees**'

Column headers in Assignees = *Agent-Name, Number of Tasks*

Spreadsheet's third tab name = '**Output**'

Column headers in Output = *Task-ID, Task-Details, Assigned-Date, Assigned-To*

The **Source** can have N number of rows. In **Assignees**, Task manager needs to just enter the Number of task one Agent can work. The task manager will assign the count of tasks for each agent in Assignees tab. Based on the counts, the **output** sheet will populate with the count of tasks for each agent from the Source.

I am very new to Google Apps Script, and I am unable to find a way through which I can accomplish this automation. It'd be kind if anyone can assist me on this. Let me know if you need more info.

Looking forward to your assistance!!

Comment: Do you have any code examples of what you have achieved so far? If not, this is probably a good resource to start: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview

Comment: @Pellay - I have worked on just an email automation, and that's no way similar to this. I understand the basic, but I am far from creating the successful logic for this. Can you please help me here?

Comment: You need to be more precise. E.g., how to you want to allocate tasks if there are only a few tasks but many people with different capacities. Assign an equal amount of task to all? Assign more task to people that have a higher capacity (and hence work faster?) and lots of other scenarios. You may need to define e.g. a time per task KPI for each assignee and then determine a goal for your algorithm which could be **minimal lead time** or it could be **equal distribution of tasks** or others. Effectively your dealing with [scheduling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheduling_(computing)).

Comment: Your solution can be anywhere from simple **first come, first serve** to complex multi-lane priority queues, which I don't think you need, but my point is, you should think about what exactly it is you need and then start thinking about how you could achieve it and only then start coding. There is no uniform answer for this.

Comment: @Mushroomator - Assigning amount of tasks is completely manual. The Task Manager will decide how many tasks one agent needs to work, and that would be specified in the second column of Assignees tab. So suppose, if Source has 10 rows of tasks, and in Assignees, there are 3 agents, and the task manager has assigned 3 count of tasks for each, then the Source tab will have only 1 task left, and remaining 9 tasks will be in Output tab, where 3 would be assigned to each. If Number of tasks in Assignees is more than Tasks in Source, then the remaining (shortage) will be ignored.

Comment: So are you saying tasks are moved from Source to Output depending on number of assignments per Assignee(s)?   If a task is added to Source and the manager increases the number of tasks in an Assignee's column its moved to Output. And does it matter which task is assigned to who?

Comment: @TheWizEd - Thanks for helping me, however, the task manager isn't supposed to assign task one by one to an assignee. Instead, the task manager will use the Assignees tab to specify the max number of task an assignee can get. 
This means that tasks will more from Source to Output depending on number of tasks assigned in Assignees tab. Please note that it does not matter which task is assigned to whom. Your solution is helpful, but can we directly have the list of tasks per assignee based on the number of tasks assigned in Assignees tab by Task manager??? Please

Comment: @TheWizEd - Just wanted to follow up and check wherther I was able to explain the situation here? Please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

**Description**

Let me propose this instead.  I have created a simple spreadsheet with your 3 sheets, Source, Assignees, and Output.  On Assignees I have a list of agents, the number of tasks assigned and the maximum number of tasks they can be assigned.  I also create a Named Range called Agents.

[image]

Now on the Source sheet I have the list of unassigned tasks.  And under Assigned-To a dropdown list of agents using Data Validation.

[image]

Once you select an agent from the Assigned-To column the number of task assigned to the agent will be incremented, the row removed from Source and added to Output.

Everything is handled through the onEdit(e) simple trigger.

**Code.gs**

```
function onEdit(e) {
  try {
    if( e.value === undefined ) {
      return;
    }
    else if( e.range.getSheet().getName() === "Source" ) {
      if( e.range.getColumn() === 3 ) {
        if( ( e.value !== null ) && ( e.value !== "" ) ) {
          // First lets find the Agent in Assignees
          let agents = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getNamedRanges();
          agents = agents.find( range => range.getName() === "Agents" );
          let index = agents.getRange().getValues().findIndex( row => row[0] === e.value );
          let agent = agents.getRange().offset(index,0,1,3).getValues();
          // Now lets check the task count
          if( agent[0][1] < agent[0][2] ) {
            agents.getRange().offset(index,1,1,1).setValue(agent[0][1]+1);
            // Move row from Source to Output
            let source = e.range.offset(0,-2,1,3).getValues(); // source is a 2D array with 1 row
            source[0].splice(2,0,new Date());
            e.source.getSheetByName("Output").appendRow(source[0]);
            e.range.getSheet().deleteRow(e.range.getRow());
          }
          else {
            SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Agent "+agent[0][0]+" has reached their limit");
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  catch(err) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(err);
  }
}
```

**Reference**

- [onEdit(e) trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/)
- [Trigger event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)
- [Spreadsheet.getNamedRanges()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getNamedRanges())
- [Array.find()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_find.asp)
- [Array.findIndex()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_findindex.asp)
- [Range.offset()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#offset(Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer))

Comment: Just wanted to follow up and check wherther I was able to explain the situation above (before solution)? Please let me know

Comment: I think it would be best for you to examine the code I provided.  Everything is there that can make it work the way you want.  My motto "teach a man to fish".